# Цикл, при вызове которого снимаются флажки с чекбоксов

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть цикл, при вызове которого, должны сниматься флажки со всех чекбоксов на форме:

```
private void Uncheck_All()
    {
        foreach (CheckBox cb in Controls)
            cb.Checked = false;
    }
```

Но при вызове программа вылетает с сообщением:

> "System.InvalidCastException: "Не удалось привести тип объекта
>   "System.Windows.Forms.Label" к типу "System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox".""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
foreach(Control c in Controls)
{
  CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
  if (cb != null) 
  {
    cb.Checked = false;
  }
}
```

или

```
using System.Linq;

...
foreach(CheckBox cb in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
  cb.Checked = false;
}
```